find the centers of the parts of the object in blender and write them down
I have been fighting with gpt for 2 days now and I can't win(
I have an object with a fairly curved shape

I need to visually divide the object into 25 parts by Y and find out the deviation of their center from the coordinate center for each of these parts. In other words, the position of their center
After each part, you need to write down this value, I think it will be easier to save it in the Color Attribute. Blue color for positive deviation and red for negative deviation
This is how it looks in manual execution on a simplified model
The value depends on the degree of deviation from the center In the case of the green part, this is (0, 0.576172, 0) Blue (0, 0, 0.52214)
We are sort of looking for where the geometric center of the project would be if the object consisted only of this part

I would be grateful for any help.

"I have been fighting with gpt for 2 days now" - imagine spending the 2 days on actually learning Python... So you want to divide the coordinate space of the object into 25 equal y-sections (I see the green line), and for each face find the face's distance to the nearest section's y-coordinate? Are you sure you want Python for this? As it's easier in geonodes. Also: why you need this? It might be an XY problem... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

this is definitely not an XY problem
I need this information to correct the position of other objects. I need them to be attached to the center of the object part

Hello, what do you mean by "center" ?

@Gorgious point is important, especially if the cross-sections are not circular, and/or the plane of the cross-section is not defined

Can you present an example of some perhaps simpler geometry (less than 25 parts, maybe 5), input (before) and output (after)?

added an explanation for simplified models, I hope it will be clearer
Sorry for the confusion, this project is just very important to me.

Sorry it still looks like this is missing some parts, maybe this is a barrier language ? A center is the point that is equally distant from all the points of a circle, here I don't see any circle. Do you mean the median displacement along Z axis ? It looks like all subdivisions have the same span along the Z axis ?
